# I want to stop audio when other button is clicked and then play another audio

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i have many Imageviews to play sound when clicked and i managed to play it.
but the problem that when i want to click on another image which supposed to play another sound, it stops the sound but i can't resume if it was clicked on the same play button.

Here is the code I've managed to get it to work so far:

```
audio1 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.lesson1_audio_gramar_1);
            assert audio1 != null;
            audio1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Activity.this, R.raw.lesson1);
                    }


                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                        mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        audio1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_48dp);
                        try {
                            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {

                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        audio1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_black_48dp);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                    }
                }
            });

            audio2 = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.lesson1_audio_gramar_2);
            assert audio2 != null;
            audio2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Lesson1Activity.this, R.raw.lesson2);
                    }

                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                        mMediaPlayer.pause();
                        audio2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_48dp);
                        try {
                            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        audio2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled_black_48dp);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

                    }


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play another track, follow this simple steps:

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
  if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
     mediaPlayer.stop();
     mediaPlayer.reset()
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(new music to play);
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
  }
}
```

Then call `mediaPlayer.start()` in the `onPrepared()` method